# requirement vs policy

Tags: word-choice, style

Since I first used "requiring", should I use "requirement" to reflect "requiring"? Or, is it good to use words like "policy"?

> **Requiring** professionals to stay in the country where they received training could help the country to avoid brain drain. Without this
> **requirement/policy**, many highly trained people would move to another country that pays better and offers a higher standard of
> living.

Comment: It's entirely a stylistic choice whether you use ***requirement*** or ***policy*** or some other term such as ***approach, arrangement, action, protocol, scheme, strategy, stratagem,...*** in this context. It's splitting hairs to claim the choice could affect the *meaning* in any way - whichever word you put after ***this***, the context makes it absolutely clear you're referring back to preceding ***requiring** [someone to do something]*. It's not relevant that ***requirement*** derives from the same root as ***requiring*** (most readers wouldn't even notice that).

Comment: It is unclear why you think that it might be "good" to use words like "policy". Is it only in order to avoid repetition?

Comment: "policy" works here; "requirement" is subtly wrong. A requirement is not the fact of requiring something — it's a prerequisite, a condition. At least most typically, without stretching.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, I think "policy" may be good because what I wrote sounds like a policy. I didn't know the difference between policy and requirement. But after reading Luke's comment, now I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's entirely a stylistic choice whether you use requirement or policy or some other term such as approach, arrangement, action, protocol, scheme, strategy, or stratagem,... in this context. It's splitting hairs to claim the choice could affect the meaning in any way - whichever word you put after this, the context makes it absolutely clear you're referring back to the preceding requiring [someone to do something]. It's not relevant that requirement derives from the same root as requiring (most readers wouldn't even notice that).

Comment: Comment to CW service